# Rails 3.2 js.erb file escaping JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I am confused by something.

I am using a js.erb file to show me a list of products fetched from the server. What I am confused at is how I can do this in js.erb file and it works:

```
<ul class="list-bordered" id="products">
    <%= render_cell :businesses, :index, {:businesses => @businesses} %>
</ul>

<%= render :partial => 'partials/infinite', :locals => {:segment => businesses_path, :container => '#businesses'} %>
```

and every other JS code is escaped, thus

```
var t = 0;
```

is output in the page as "var t=0;"

I checked the server logs and the response is indeed JS. I am using respond_with, and checked that I am indeed responding to JS requests.

**SIDE QUESTION**: Speaking in a "best practice way", is it alright to have html code inside a .js.erb file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are firing an AJAX request, it's data type is `script` now and in a `.js.erb` file you can write Javascript code easily .

```
$("#products").html("<%=escape_javascript(render_cell :businesses, :index, {:businesses => @businesses}%>")
```

Now you can manipulate your `.js.erb` or HTML as per your wish; it's just an example how can you render a partial in a `.js.erb`.

Now suppose you are rendering HTML on the client side (considering data type is `text/html`). On an AJAX success, you have to replace that HTML.